# Is there a way to get Gmail Chat recipient details?

Tags: gmail-api, google-hangouts

I'm trying to find the recipient info in the Gmail with the label CHAT. Normally with other Gmail messages, the payload header should return the sender, recipient, cc and bcc information. But the recipient info is missing in the payload header when I try to get the Gmail Chat. I've tried the metadataHeader and wasn't not able to return the recipient format. Is there a way to get the recipient info?

I've been using this page to test the API. 
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get

Example -
When I sent a chat message to User B, I would like to get the message recipient from the api. The returned json below only shows that I send the message, but not who received the message.

Returned Json -

```
 "id": "xxxx",
 "threadId": "xxxx",
 "labelIds": [
  "CHAT"
 ],
 "snippet": "asdfasdfasdf",
 "historyId": "171386",
 "internalDate": "1586440732637",
 "payload": {
  "partId": "",
  "mimeType": "text/html",
  "filename": "",
  "headers": [
   {
    "name": "From",
    "value": "Admin Admin \u003cxxx@xxx.com\u003e"
   }
  ],
  "body": {
   "size": 12,
   "data": "YXNkZmFzZGZhc2Rm"
  }
 },
 "sizeEstimate": 100
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Hello @ycbencheng, the recipient info should be the one you inputted at the `userId` when doing the request. Would you mind providing more details about what exactly are you trying to achieve? Cheers!

Comment: In the request params, the userId returns the threads of the user (let's say Alice). Then if we look at a message from one of her threads, there is no data that tells me who the message was sent to from Alice. The headers just tell me again that the message was from Alice. No recipient information. @ale13

Comment: Hello @ycbencheng, I think I understand now. So you are trying to retrieve the `to` from a chat message using the Gmail API. But since the message is not an email per se, it won't have the structure of a regular email. So you might want to try using the Hangouts Chat API if you want to retrieve that. Does that work for your situation? Cheers!